# In which church do the French royalists meet?

Tags: france, paris, history

Rumours go that there is still a small, but active community of French royalists. They apparently meet regularly in a church close to the Seine in Paris.

Is this rumour true, if so can I join their meetings and where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many distinct and rivalling royalists groupuscules in France so it seems unlikely that there is *one* answer to this question.

It's not explicitly royalist (or even political at all) but the [Fraternity St. Pius X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_St._Pius_X) tends to be associated with the most conservative quarters of French society, including some royalists. In France, one of their most well-known centers is [Saint-Nicolas-du-Chardonnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Nicolas-du-Chardonnet). It's not far from the Seine so it might be the source of the rumour you heard.

Otherwise, [there is this](http://www.messes-louisxvi.com/) (you will note that a number of these masses are celebrated following the tridentine rite and some of the clerics and churches involved are, in fact, associated with SSPX).

Comment: That was the church I was looking for. It is just fascinating that these groups exist. Recently I met a orangist in Belgium, which is also an active group of Belgians loyal to the Dutch royals.

Comment: @andra: If you want to join a meeting, I guess you can speak French. If my guess is correct, you may find interesting information about French royalists in the nationalist newspaper *Action Francaise* (it promotes the come back to absolute monarchy in France)